# Is there a way to serialize a class between C++ CLI and C#

Tags: c#, serialization, c++-cli

I know answer is probably no, but I would like to be sure, because it would save me a lot of trouble.
To explain:
I would like to have C++ CLI class that uses only .net containers and regular ints, doubles...
and I would like to be able to serialize that CLI class and deserialize it into a "same" class that is written in C#.

Comment: Do you mean 'serialize' and 'deserialize' the source code, or simply use the same class in both C# and C++?

Comment: do you want to serialize or do you want to marshal? I mean, are there at least two processes where you want to exchange objects?

Comment: Sorry...Let me rephrase my question: Do you mean serialize an OBJECT or a class? Serializing a class makes a lot less sense...

Comment: I want to have 2 "same" classes in C# and in C++ CLI. I want to be able to transfer values of members from one instance of C# class to one instance of C++ CLI class throught text file. I have managed to do that, following advice from accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you can use any .Net serialization mechanism.
(binary, XML, DataContract, ...)

As long as you don't use any unmanaged code, there is no fundamental difference between managed types written in C++/CLI and managed types written in C#.

Note that .Net binary serialization cannot operate between equivalent types; to use binary serialization, you would need to define the types in a library and reference the library from both projects.

Comment: Hi, XML (De)Serialization works, except when I have nested class. Is that possible to fix or I have to manually deserialize nested in containing's class method?

Comment: nevermind, it got fixed magically (try, fail, finally dont know when you fixed it :))

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a `BinaryWriter` to serialise it manually, and a `BinaryReader` to deserialise it. It's not automatic, so you have to update the code if you change the class, but it performs better than any dynamic serialisation.